# Updating image constantly in Xamarin forms using PCL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an image on a screen that I'd like to update every 100ms to give it the effect of animation. I'm trying to run it asynchronously so that it doesn't get in the way of the UI thread, not to mention there's no reason to run it on the main thread.

The problem is the memory is not being cleared in between images, so after the 19th (of 39) image, the thread runs out of memory, crashing the app. Is there a way I can force the thread to clear the memory? Code is below.

```
private async void AnimateImage(List<String> imagePath)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < imagePath.Count)
            {
                try
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("i is currently {0}, images.Count is {1}", i, imagePath.Count);
                    instructionAnimation.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imagePath.ElementAt(i));

                    await Task.Delay(50);

                    if (++i == imagePath.Count)
                    {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }

            }
            return;
        }
```

Comment: You can place a `GC.Collect()` within your while loop

Comment: Try some image loading libraries instead.